# How do i print each character a part in C#

Tags: c#, console

How do I ask for a number to be inputed and then check if the number given is a 5 digit one and print them all one by one. 
E.g.   the number 12345 need to be printed in console as: 
1
2
3
4
5
Using the Modulus(%).

Thank you

Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int number = 12345;
    int countOfDigit = number.ToString().Length;

    for (int i = 1; i <= countOfDigit; i++)
    {
        int digit = number / (int)Math.Pow(10, countOfDigit - i)
        var result = digit % 10;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Or without '/' and '%' :

```
var number = 12345;
foreach (var item in number.ToString().ToCharArray())
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```